# How can I decorate on a mug or plate with paper?

Tags: paper, adhesives, ceramics, food-safe

I remember when I was in school and the teacher gave us just newspaper. We cut words from it and decorated our mug or plate. I don't remember how we glued or adhered to the plate or mug so it was permanent.
Do  you know a way how to fix pieces of (news)paper to a white mug or plate, so it is

- permanent
- non-toxic
- food-safe

It does not have to be newspaper specifically, any common household paper (or alternative materials) should work for this.

Comment: Questions do need to have a clear goal so sticking to paper for _this question_ would be better. If you have other questions beyond that then that is a good opportunity for a new question!

Comment: I google searched "food safe sealer" and found this website: https://theepoxyexperts.com/shop/adhesives/max-clr-24-oz-epoxy-resin-food-safe-fda-compliant-clear-high-impact-coating/

Answer (score 3):

You can use mod podge (decoupage glue) to decoupage your paper designs onto the mugs and plates - there are many tutorials for decoupage all over the he internet.

Once your decoupaged mugs / plates are completely dry and cured (leave it for a few days to be sure) you can apply several thin coats of a water based polyurethane varnish (leaving plenty of time for each layer to dry) to seal it and make it food and dishwasher safe.

Answer (score 2):

You're not going to be able to adhere paper to any piece that will be kiln fired.

Alternate options include adding those paper clippings to fired pieces and then sealing them with some kind of varnish coating, or creating stencils or screens for screen printing your text/designs. There are places that will create custom screens if this is your desire. As for stencils, for about $300 you can buy a stencil cutter, provided you can import the images you want. You may also be able to find this service online, I've never looked so I can't say.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider [photo lithography image transfer onto clay](https://youtu.be/MolPVW2EaBY). If you want it to be a bit easier than that, then [ceramic decal paper](https://youtu.be/oBrS6a1c_TE) is another option.